# How to add List<T> containing item of type List<string> ,int,string into another List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have a list with complex data

```
public class CAR
{    
public int ID {get ; set ; }
public string Name { get ; set ; }
public string EngineType { get ; set ; }
public List<string> Months { get; set; }

}
```

Note that `Months` data is `List<string>` its max count is `150`

```
List<CAR> A = new List<CAR>();
List<CAR> B = new List<CAR>();
```

`A` has follwoing data

```
 ID  |  Name  | EngineType |  Months[0] | Months[1] |  Months[2] |  Months[3]  .. | Months[149] | 
   1   |  Zen   |  1001      |  1         | 1         |  4         |  5        ..   | 6           |
   2   |  Benz  |  2002      |  6         | 4         |  5         |  6        ..   | 2           |
   3   |  Zen   |  1001      |  3         | 1         |  7         |  5        ..   | 0           |
   4   |  Zen   |  1001      |  2         | 2         |  4         |  5        ..   | 6           |
   5   |  Zen   |  2002      |  2         | 2         |  4         |  5        ..   | 6           |
   6   |  Benz  |  2002      |  1         | 1         |  1         |  1        ..   | 1           |
```

IF `EngineType` and `Name` are same we add those rows and store the result in a single row 
Eg : adding rows

```
row 1 in B =     1 + 3 + 4
row 2 in B =     2 + 6
row 3 in B =     5
```

`B` should contain the following op

```
   ID  |  Name  | EngineType |  Months[0] | Months[1] |  Months[2] |  Months[3] ... | Months[149] | 
   -   |  Zen   |  Petrol    |  6         | 4         |  15        |  15       ..   | 12          |
   -   |  Benz  |  Diesel    |  7         | 5         |  6         |  7             | 3           |        
   -   |  Zen   |  Diesel    |  2         | 2         |  4         |  5        ..   | 6           |
```

had months data been separate entity of type integer something else i could have done this

```
B = from val in A 
      group val by  new val.EngineType into g 
          select new CAR{
        EngineType = g.Key, 
        Name = g.Name,
                Month0 = g.Sum(p => p.Month0),
                Month1 = g.Sum(p => p.Month1),
                Month2 = g.Sum(p => p.Month2),
            .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
                Month148 = g.Sum(p => p.Month148),
                Month149 = g.Sum(p => p.Month149)
}.ToList<CAR>();
```

But since its of type `List<string>` is there a way to get this done?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You would have to `Parse` the strings into numbers, perform your calculations, and then `ToString()` the result into the target strings.

Comment: On another note, your last code example seems wrong.  It should be `Month[0]`, and you probably should be using a loop instead of assigning each month individually.

Comment: instead of coming up with such ugly and unmaintainable code and methods, i d break it down to reusable methods/components. What you are doing doesnt feel right in the first place. then if you have the data in memory, breaking down these into smaller methods wouldnt hurt performance anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the power of LINQ:

```
var B = A.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.EngineType })
         .Select(g => new Car
         {
             Name = g.Key.Name,
             EngineType = g.Key.EngineType,
             Months = g.SelectMany(x => x.Months.Select((y,i) => new { i, y = int.Parse(y) }))
                       .GroupBy(x => x.i)
                       .OrderBy(g2 => g2.Key)
                       .Select(g2 => g2.Sum(x => x.y).ToString()).ToList()
         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (CAR c in A)
        {
            bool blnadded = false;
            if (B.Count == 0)
            {
                B.Add(c);
                blnadded = true;
            }
            else
                foreach (CAR d in B)
                {
                    if (d.Name == c.Name && d.EngineType == c.EngineType)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < d.Months.Count; i++)
                            d.Months[i] = (Convert.ToInt32(d.Months[i]) + Convert.ToInt32(c.Months[i])).ToString();
                        blnadded = true;
                    }
                }
            if (blnadded==false)
                B.Add(c);
        }
```